# Google App Engine Datastore - Keys vs. Identifiers

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

One decision that I have run into a few times is how to handle passing around either the key or embedded IDs of the entities. Each seems equally feasible given the encoders and marshalling methods built in with the datastore keys, but I was wondering if there is any sort of best practice on this choice. An example might be for a URL accessing a user’s files, where users have the default auto-generated numerical IDs, of the form: `website.com/users/{userIdentifier}/files`

I am trying to determine whether the number embedded in the datastore keys is preferable to the actual key strings themselves. Is it safe to have datastore keys out in the wild? I would like to standardize the way we handle those identifiers across our system and was wondering if there are any best practices on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason to use a full Key as opposed to an identifier is to get the ancestor information embedded in the key itself without passing an additional data. While this may be convenient in some cases, I don't think it's a big enough of an advantage to use keys as a standard method of reference within an app.

The advantages of using an identifier are more substantial: (a) they are much smaller, and (b) they do not reveal any information about their ancestors (which may or may not be an issue).

The smaller size comes into play quite often: you may want to use an id in a URL, hold a list of ids in a memcache (which has a 1MB limit), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Datastore keys contain (*at least*) next information:

- Kind
- Reference to ancestor
- String or Int ID

Do you really need/want to pass in URL or keep in your DB AppID & Kind?

Compare this 2 urls (logically, in case of key it would be probably encoded with `urlsafe()`):

- /list-of-orders?user=123
- /list-of-orders?user=User/123

Or this 2 fields:

```
Table: Orders
---------------------
| UserKey  | UserID |
---------------------
| User/123 | 123    |
---------------------
```

Why would you want to keep & pass around repetitive information about app & kind? Usually your app reference its own entities and kind is known by column or parameter name.

Unless you build some orchestration/integration between few apps it's more effective to use just IDs.